# Ansible - other tasks in block are skipped after rescue is called

Tags: ansible

I am intentionally creating an error in first task (`create file-1`) in block to handle error. The rescue block triggers fine and does the job but then the second task (`create file-2`) in block is not executed at all.
 Why so? how can I ensure that all tasks in my block are executed?

My playbook. Please note the commented lines
[image]

Comment: Please don't post *pictures* of text. Post the text itself, properly formatted. This makes your question more discoverable (e.g. via search engines) and makes your question accessible to people using screen readers or other assistive devices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your playbook is behaving correctly. A `rescue` block is a form of exception handling. It allows you to catch and respond to an error that would otherwise cause your playbook to exit, but all other tasks in the block will be skipped. Playbook execution will continue *after* the current block.

If you want to ensure that the second task executes, you could place them in two separate blocks:

```
- block:
    - name: create file-1
      command: touch /path/to/file-1.txt
  rescue:
    - name: handle error
      debug:
        msg: do some error handling here

- block:
    - name: create file-2
      command: touch /path/to/file-2.txt
      register: file1
  rescue:
    - name: handle error
      debug:
        msg: do some error handling here
```

Or set `ignore_errors: true` on the `create file-<n>` blocks and explicitly check for errors after they have both executed:

```
- name: create file-1
  command: touch /path/to/file-1.txt
  register: file1
  ignore_errors: true

- name: handle errors creating file-1
  debug:
    msg: do something here
  when: file1 is failed

- name: create file-2
  command: touch /path/to/file-2.txt
  register: file2
  ignore_errors: true

- name: handle errors creating file-1
  debug:
    msg: do something here
  when: file2 is failed
```